# CSS style on :hover to another element

Tags: html, css, hover

How when I hover on the `<li>`I can select my `<a>`element ?

```css
a ul:hover {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">Link</a>
<ul>
  <li>Element 1</li>
  <li>Element 2</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using [`:has`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has) like this:

```css
a:has(+ ul:hover) {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">Link</a>
<ul>
  <li>Element 1</li>
  <li>Element 2</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

For those browsers which support :has you can use:

```html
<style>
  a:has(+ ul li:hover) {
    background: red;
  }
</style>
<a href="#">Link</a>
<ul>
  <li>Element 1</li>
  <li>Element 2</li>
</ul>
```

However, check on caniuse.com that there is enough support for your use case - Edge/Chrome/Safari support it but Firefox requires a flag to be set.